# Python variable does not contain any data

Tags: python

I'm hoping this is a simple stupid problem. But we have an in-house program that is no longer working. The program is not able to pass the data which is supposed to be contained in a variable using var_name+="".

The variable seemingly contains nothing. when I try to print the contents of this variable to either a string or text doc, we get nothing. The variable in question here is "allData".

The contents of this variable need to be passed to our fax appliance.

```
def sendFax(destOrg, destFax, cliName, casenum, attachments, errEAddr, comment, destName):
    creds=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(user,password)

    #OVERRIDE OUTBOUND FAX NUMBER FOR TESTING
    destFax='716-631-9804'
    print("faxes will be sent to "+destFax)
    return

allData=''
allData+='<schedule_fax>\n'

allData+='<cover_page>\n'
allData+='<url>'+prepXMLString(coverPage)+'</url>\n'
allData+='<enabled>true</enabled>\n'
allData+='<subject>'+prepXMLString(cliName)+' - case # '+str(casenum)+'</subject>\n'
allData+='<comments>'+prepXMLString(comment)+'</comments>\n'
allData+='</cover_page>\n'

allData+='<sender>\n'
allData+='<name>'+prepXMLString(webAddr)+'</name>\n'
allData+='<organization>'+prepXMLString(ourOrg)+'</organization>\n'
allData+='<phone_number>'+prepXMLString(ourPhonenum)+'</phone_number>\n'
allData+='<fax_number>'+prepXMLString(ourFaxnum)+'</fax_number>\n'
allData+='<email_address>'+prepXMLString(errEAddr)+'</email_address>\n'
allData+='</sender>\n'

allData+='<recipient>\n'
allData+='<name>'+prepXMLString(destName)+'</name>\n'
allData+='<organization>'+prepXMLString(destOrg)+'</organization>\n'
allData+='<fax_number>'+destFax+'</fax_number>\n'
allData+='</recipient>\n'
```

Comment: why there is a return above all data

Comment: Please check your indentation, whitespace at the beginning of lines matters

Comment: "The variable seemingly contains nothing. when I try to print the contents of this variable to either a string or text doc, we get nothing. The variable in question here is "allData"." That isn't possible. Variables cannot be "empty" in Python, they always have a value. Are you getting a `NameError`? As noted in the previous comment, your function seems to `return` before `allData` is assigned to,  in any case, you aren't printing anything here, so what **exactly** are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is all screwed up. You're returning on the line with the `return` keyword which is why nothing is being returned.

You should do all of the concatenation and then return.